# Send Text Messages from Salesforce with no licensing cost

Tags: sms

How to send text messages from salesforce?. There are a lot of apps available on appExchange/Marketing cloud to send text messages. Both of these solutions comes with an additional cost. we are sending Email without appExchange/Marketing using "Messaging.SingleEmailMessage".like we have any possibility way to send text messages Through salesforce only.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: did you check smsMagic? are you asking for free?

Comment: There is no native SMS sending feature available in Salesforce . Only you can send emails. You have to use a appexchange app or build a custom solution with APIs available from different Cloud Telephonies like Twilio and Plivo.

Comment: @Santanu Boral  am asking free feature in salesforce

Comment: @Saroj Bera Any free trial appexchange app or build a custom solution with APIs available ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Salesforce cannot do this natively (at time of writing, and I haven't seen anything in a roadmap to suggest that such a feature would be coming).

What you're looking for is called an "SMS Gateway", and it is not likely that you will be able to find one that is free of cost.

It is also not feasible to build your own SMS Gateway.

Your best bet is to use one of those paid App Exchange apps.